# Model accuracy Not Increasing while using Tensorflow-datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm Trying to classify Dog and Cat images using **tensorflow-datasets**, but my loss and accuracy doesn't seem to change no matter how many epochs I run it for.

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

dataset_name = 'cats_vs_dogs'
dataset, info= tfds.load(name=dataset_name, split=tfds.Split.TRAIN, with_info=True)


def preprocess(features):
    print(features['image'], features['label'])
    image = tf.image.resize(features['image'], [224,224])
    image = tf.divide(image, 255)
    print(image)
    label = features['label']
    print(label)
    return image, label

def solution_model():
    train_dataset = dataset.map(preprocess).batch(32)

    model = tf.keras.Sequential( 
        [
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), input_shape=(224, 224, 3), activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')
        ]
    )
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=100, verbose= 2)

    return model


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = solution_model()
    model.save("mymodel.h5")
```

I'm getting the same results no matter how many times I run it. I just get the same result:

```
Epoch 1/100
727/727 - 51s - loss: 7.6423 - accuracy: 0.4988
Epoch 2/100
727/727 - 51s - loss: 7.6423 - accuracy: 0.4988
Epoch 3/100
727/727 - 51s - loss: 7.6423 - accuracy: 0.4988
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not linked to the use of TensorFlow datasets, but the use of the softmax layer at the end of your network.

The output shape of your network is a single scalar (0 for cat, 1 for dog). Using the softmax on a scalar makes it always go to 1, hence your loss & accuracy being stucked: you always predict 1 whatever the input.

Instead, you should probably use a simple sigmoid which better match your use case, and keep the softmax to cases where the output shape is not a single scalar (e.g for one-hot encoded targets).

Modified code below (I tested it and it learns something):

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

dataset_name = 'cats_vs_dogs'
dataset, info= tfds.load(name=dataset_name, split=tfds.Split.TRAIN, with_info=True)


def preprocess(features):
    print(features['image'], features['label'])
    image = tf.image.resize(features['image'], [224,224])
    image = tf.divide(image, 255)
    print(image)
    label = features['label']
    print(label)
    return image, tf.cast(label, tf.float32)

def solution_model():
    train_dataset = dataset.map(preprocess).batch(32)

    model = tf.keras.Sequential( 
        [
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), input_shape=(224, 224, 3), activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='sigmoid'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
        ]
    )
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=100, verbose=1)

    return model


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = solution_model()
    model.save("mymodel.h5")
```